# Working with Logs (with multiline) and Regex

Tags: c#, regex, expression

Having the following LOG:

```
2014-02-13 16:06:52,226 [8] ERROR solucao.projeto.arquivo - AutenticarUsuario
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: O thread estava sendo anulado.
    em System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
    em System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
    em System.Web.HttpResponse.End()  
2014-02-13 16:06:52,226 [8] ERROR solucao.projeto.arquivo - AutenticarUsuario
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: O thread estava sendo anulado.
   em System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   em System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   em System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
```

Trying to recover using a regex expression, I can not retrieve the full text that belongs to the exception.

```
(?<data>\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\,\d{3})\s\[(?<thread>[0-9]+)\]\s(?<nivel>[A-Z]+)\s(?<classe>([A-Za-z]+\.)+[A-Za-z]+)\s\-\s(?<metodo>[A-Za-z_]+)\n(?<message>.+)
```

How I can do to recover the full exception?

Comment: can you add a sample output , not pretty sure what exactly you want, and your regex seems to be an overkill

Comment: This is the example I'm working on: [http://regex101.com/r/oC9mM1](http://regex101.com/r/oC9mM1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of your individual captures, but something like this should work

```
 #  @"(?ms)^(?<data>[^\[\]\r\n]+)[ \t]+\[(?<thread>[0-9]+)\][ \t]+(?<nivel>[A-Z]+)[ \t]+(?<classe>(?:[A-Za-z]+\.)+[A-Za-z]+)[ \t]+-[ \t]+(?<message>(?:(?!^[^\[\]\r\n]+[ \t]+\[[0-9]+\]).)+)"

 (?ms)                                   # Multi-line, Dot-All
 ^                                       # Beginning of line
 (?<data> [^\[\]\r\n]+ )                 # (1), Date/time                                             
 [ \t]+                                  # Horizontal whitespace ( could use '\h' instead )
 \[                                      # '['
 (?<thread> [0-9]+ )                     # (2), Thread number                                             
 \]                                      # ']'
 [ \t]+                                  # Horizontal whitespace 
 (?<nivel> [A-Z]+ )                      # (3), Error                                    
 [ \t]+                                  # Horizontal whitespace
 (?<classe>                              # (4 start), Class                                    
      (?: [A-Za-z]+ \. )+
      [A-Za-z]+ 
 )                                       # (4 end)
 [ \t]+                                  # Horizontal whitespace
 -                                       # '-'
 [ \t]+                                  # Horizontal whitespace
 (?<message>                             # (5 start), Message                           
      (?:                                     # Cluster group
           (?!                                     # Lookahead
                ^                                       # Not the start of a new exception
                [^\[\]\r\n]+                            # ( basically, not the above code )
                [ \t]+ 
                \[
                [0-9]+ 
                \]
           )                                       # End Lookahead
           .                                       # Continue to grab characters
      )+                                      # End Cluster group, do 1 or more times
 )                                       # (5 end)
```

**edit**  (Removed Perl test case. Added C# test case)

C# test case

```
string sLog =
@"
2014-02-13 16:06:52,226 [8] ERROR solucao.projeto.arquivo - AutenticarUsuario
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: O thread estava sendo anulado.
    em System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
    em System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
    em System.Web.HttpResponse.End()  
2014-02-13 16:06:52,226 [8] ERROR solucao.projeto.arquivo - AutenticarUsuario
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: O thread estava sendo anulado.
   em System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   em System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   em System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
";

Regex Rx = new Regex(
@"
 (?ms)                                   # Multi-line, Dot-All
 ^                                       # Beginning of line
 (?<data> [^\[\]\r\n]+ )                 # (1), Date/time                                             
 [ \t]+                                  # Horizontal whitespace ( could use '\h' instead )
 \[                                      # '['
 (?<thread> [0-9]+ )                     # (2), Thread number                                             
 \]                                      # ']'
 [ \t]+                                  # Horizontal whitespace 
 (?<nivel> [A-Z]+ )                      # (3), Error                                    
 [ \t]+                                  # Horizontal whitespace
 (?<classe>                              # (4 start), Class                                    
      (?: [A-Za-z]+ \. )+
      [A-Za-z]+ 
 )                                       # (4 end)
 [ \t]+                                  # Horizontal whitespace
 -                                       # '-'
 [ \t]+                                  # Horizontal whitespace
 (?<message>                             # (5 start), Message                           
      (?:                                     # Cluster group
           (?!                                     # Lookahead
                ^                                       # Not the start of a new exception
                [^\[\]\r\n]+                            # ( basically, not the above code )
                [ \t]+ 
                \[
                [0-9]+ 
                \]
           )                                       # End Lookahead
           .                                       # Continue to grab characters
      )+                                      # End Cluster group, do 1 or more times
 )                                       # (5 end)
", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

Match matchX = Rx.Match( sLog );
while ( matchX.Success )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "----------------------" );
    Console.WriteLine( "New Exception" );
    Console.WriteLine( "Date:\t" + matchX.Groups[1] );
    Console.WriteLine( "Thread:\t" + matchX.Groups[2] );
    Console.WriteLine( "Err:\t" + matchX.Groups[3] );
    Console.WriteLine( "Class:\t" + matchX.Groups[4] ) ;
    Console.WriteLine( "Msg --" );
    Console.WriteLine( matchX.Groups[5] );
    matchX = matchX.NextMatch();
}
```

Output >>

```
----------------------
New Exception
Date:   2014-02-13 16:06:52,226
Thread: 8
Err:    ERROR
Class:  solucao.projeto.arquivo
Msg --
AutenticarUsuario
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: O thread estava sendo anulado.
    em System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
    em System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
    em System.Web.HttpResponse.End()

----------------------
New Exception
Date:   2014-02-13 16:06:52,226
Thread: 8
Err:    ERROR
Class:  solucao.projeto.arquivo
Msg --
AutenticarUsuario
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: O thread estava sendo anulado.
   em System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   em System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   em System.Web.HttpResponse.End()

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: I tried to implement your example in my project and I could not make it work. [http://regex101.com/r/oC9mM1](http://regex101.com/r/oC9mM1)

Comment: @DhiogoAcioli  - Did the input change? I have an older browser, all I saw from that link was the same `input` used above. Options are `(?ms)`, Multi-Line and Dot-All (Single string). I'm going to say the regex in my example is the same as used for Dot-Net. I.e. it _works_ in my example.

Comment: @DhiogoAcioli - Added a C# test case.

Comment: In fact, you redid the whole process. I applied your example and it worked. thank you!

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't mean to redo the whole regex. Just fiddle with it to get what you need.

Comment: @DhiogoAcioli - Just a note. You can manage large Regular Expressions with this app - [RegexFormat4](http://www.regexformat.com). I formatted (expanded), modified, commented, compressed and created a verbatim regex of your original into this state in about 3 minutes. %95 of that time was changing it, everything else was a couple of button clicks. Good Luck!